# angular how to access an interface within an interface

Tags: angular

```
[This is my table ][1]
 [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNSii.png
```

this is the error cause when i make them null even though text and link url    are displayed even though if they are null as i said earlier This is from    the catalina log

```
Caused by: oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-01400: cannot insert 
 NULL into ("MYSEDV_INT2"."FAQ_SUBSECTION"."TEXT")
```

```
This is shown even though text and linkURL are null 
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ds2Ke.png
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in the interface specification. `faqSectionList` in `FAQContentDisplayBean` should be an array

```js
export interface FAQContentDisplayBean {
  oid: number;
  faqSectionList: faqSectionList[];
}
```

And you need to loop through the array to get `summaryTitle`.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let faqSection of faqSectionlist.FAQContentDisplayBean.faqSectionList">
  {{ faqSection.summaryTitle }}
</ng-container>
```

**Update - access `text` property in `faqSubsectionList`**

`faqSubsectionList` is an array within `faqSectionList`. So use an inner loop to access all `faqSubsectionList`'s properties.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let faqSection of faqSectionlist.FAQContentDisplayBean.faqSectionList">
  {{ faqSection.summaryTitle }}
  <ng-container *ngFor="let faqSubSection of faqSection.faqSubsectionList">
    {{ faqSubSection.text }}
    {{ faqSubSection.linkURL }}
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: thanks i got that but now i want to access the text property in faqsubsectionlist how to do that

Comment: @RohanSarkar: `faqSubsectionList` is an array within the `faqSectionList` array. So use an inner `*ngFor` to access all `faqSubsectionList`s of  `faqSectionList`. I've updated the code.

Comment: thanks man it worked !! i have another doubt there is are some images in my image property in faqSubsection its not loading on my webpage can u solve this issue??

Comment: <div *ngIf="faqSubsection.type==='Image'"
        id="faq{{faqSection.rank}}_{{faqSubsection.rank}}_Image">
      <img class="faq_image"
         id="faq_image"
         src={{faqSubsection.image}}
         alt="image" /><br>
      <br>
     </div>

Comment: From the screenshot in question, all  `faqSubsection.image` is `null`. Also there is a property called `faqSubsection.linkURL`. Maybe that is the correct image source value?

Comment: Then please check if the API response contains the image source URLs. Or post the entire API response.

Comment: i have edited and posted the api response check the code

Comment: That doesn't look like the API response. It is the backend code that generates the response. Please post of the actual API response.

Comment: i am new on angular and web development where can i check the api response can u please tell!!

Comment: I see that you've posted a screenshot of the console.log of the response. If you could go to the Network tab of the browser debug console you can select the HTTP request you make and copy the entire response from there.

Comment: added the api response and i did faqSubsection.fileName also it didnt work

Comment: like this ====   <img src="faqSubsection.fileName"
         alt="image"
         class="faq_image"
         id="faq_image" /><br>

Comment: `fileName` property is only the name of the file. It is not a valid value to assign to `src` property of the `img` tag. To open an image using `img` tag, the `src` property needs a valid URL or a valid base64 encoded version of the image. But from the response, all the `linkURL` and `image` properties have only the value `null`. You might have to look into how to properly send in the image in the response. There is no valid URL to open the image.

Comment: The text and linkUrl is showing even though its set to null man but the image wont...I am changing my code and putting required imformation so u can understand